# Prove that the function cannot be strictly concave on $[0,1]$

Tags: derivatives, inequality, definite-integrals, convexity-inequality

> > Let $f(x)$ be a continuous ,twice differentiable, function such that $f(1)=f(0.5)=f(0)=0$ and $\forall x\in [0,1]  f''(x)\neq -\infty$ then $f(x)$ cannot be strictly concave on the interval $[0,1]$

First remark this problem create discontinuity for some $x\in[0,1]$ and some function $f(x)$.By example the function $f(x)=-e^{\frac{-1}{x(1-x)\ln(2x)}}$ is not a counter example because $f''(0.5)=-\infty$.

Furthermore I have tried to apply the [Wirtinger's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wirtinger%27s_inequality_for_functions) wich states :

$$\pi^2\int_{0}^{a}|f(x)|^2dx\leq a^2\int_{0}^{a}|f'(x)|^2dx$$

With $f(0)=f(a)=0$ and some condition on $f(x)$.

Because if we know the behavior of $f'(x)$ it implies the behavior of $f''(x)$

I recognize we have few stuffs to prove it .

Finally I have tried to apply the following statement (p.5 in this [paper](https://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/1511/1511.05281.pdf)):

$$\frac{f(a)+f(b)}{2}-\frac{1}{b-a}\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx=\frac{(b-a)^2}{16}\int_{0}^{1}(1-t^2)\Big(f''\Big(\frac{1+t}{2}a+\frac{1-t}{2}b\Big)+f''\Big(\frac{1-t}{2}a+\frac{1+t}{2}b\Big)\Big)dt$$

Without success unfortunately .

Without all this material I think that there exists a simple proof of this fact .

So How to solve it ?

Any helps is highly appreciated .

Thanks a lot for all your contributions.

Comment: I think they want you to apply Rolle twice. Then we can show that there is some point where $f''(0)=0$ within the interval. If $f''(0)=0$ identically in the interval, then you've proved the theorem. Thus, for any function satisfying your condition apart from $f(x)=0,$ the theorem is true.

Comment: @The.old.boy   Suppose $f$ is strictly concave on $[0,1]$. For $0 < x < 1$, we have $f(x) = f(x \cdot 1 + (1-x) \cdot 0) > x f(1) + (1-x)f(0) = 0$ which contradicts $f(0.5)=0$. 
Am I right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was thinking something along the lines of using Rolle's Theorem. Since $f$ is continuous and differentiable and $f(0) = f(0.5) = f(1) = 0$, by Rolle's Theorem $\exists c \in (0, 0.5)$ and $d \in (0.5,1)$ such that $f'(c) = f'(d) = 0$. Since the derivative is continuous as well, $\exists e \in (c,d) $ such that $f''(e) = 0$. For the function to be strictly concave, $f''(x) < 0$ $\forall x \in (0,1)$ which is not true by the above argument.

Hope this helps.

Comment: You got the idea of this problem -- Rolle does it! But the last sentence of your proof betrays your understanding a little. Once you've shown that there is a point where $f''$ vanishes. Then you only need to prove that $f''$ is sometimes positive and sometimes negative in your interval. That is, it does not have fixed sign. Also, you need to rule out the case when $f''$ disappears identically.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! This is actually the first proof I wrote on my own so you can expect I would make some errors :)

Comment: Wow, that's OK. Well done!

Answer (score 2):

Continuing from where Aditya left off, you can show that $f''$ vanishes at some point *within* the given interval by applying Rolle twice.

Then since $f'$ vanishes at least twice, it follows that $f$ cannot be monotonic in the domain given. Thus if the function is not identically vanishing, then $f''$ must change sign, which concludes the proof.

Comment: +1 thanks for the help!